# For loop is overwriting dictionary values in list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

**Issue**

I've made a for loop reading the contents of a list however when assigning two values to a dictionary and then appending that output to a list, the next value overwrites everything in the list

**Desired outcome**

I want to append multiple dictionaries to a list so when I run a for loop and print everything related to 'ip' it will print all the values associated with the dictionary value 'ip'.

**Code**

```
device =  { 'ip': '', 'mac': '', 'username': 'admin', 'password': [], 'device type': '', }
listofdevices = []
def begin():
   file = open("outputfromterminal")
   contents = file.read()
   contents = contents.split(',')[1:]
   for x in contents:
     # do some text stripping
     x = x.split(' ')
     device['ip']=x[0]
     device['mac']=x[1]
     listofdevices.append(device)
```

**Sample code**

the 1st index of contents is:

```
x[0] = '10.10.10.1'
x[1] = 'aa:bb:cc:dd'
```

The 2nd index of contents is:

```
x[0] = '20.20.20.1'
x[1] = 'qq:ww:ee:ee:rr'
```

**What actually happens**

```
  listofdevices[0] 'ip': 20.20.20.1, 'mac': 'qq:ww:ee:ee:rr'
  listofdevices[1] 'ip': 20.20.20.1, 'mac': 'qq:ww:ee:ee:rr'
```

Comment: It has not much to do with the `for` loop itself: the list contains two references to the *same* dictionary.

Comment: So you're saying I'd have to use an index number to create a new dictionary and append the values to the index number relating to the dictionary?

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with using indexes either, you must construct a *new* dictionary each time.

Comment: or you can append a copy of the device using `listofdevices.append(device.copy())`

Comment: You are merely modifying and appending the *same dictionary* every time. Create a new one each iteration instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code. Each device was trying to edit the same copy of a dictionary.

```
listofdevices = []

def begin():
    with open("outputfromterminal", 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read().split(',')[1:]

    for line in contents:
        # do some text stripping
        line = line.split(' ')

        device =  { 'ip': line[0],
                    'mac': line[1],
                    'username': 'admin',
                    'password': [],
                    'device type': '',
                   }

        listofdevices.append(device)
```

Comment: Can't be "the same copy" when there's *no* copy...

Comment: What are you talking about?
There is a single copy of a dictionary in the original code. No, the dictionary hasn't been .copy()'d, but it is a copy of a dictionary.

Comment: I don't see how. It's a copy of *which* dictionary?

Comment: A copy of the built-in dict()

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a new dictionary object each time.  You are simply mutating the same object within each iteration.  Try deep copying the dictionary using the `copy` module.  Then after obtaining this copy, mutate it and append to list:

```
import copy
device =  { 'ip': '', 'mac': '', 'username': 'admin', 'password': [], 'device type': '', }
listofdevices = []
def begin():
   file = open("outputfromterminal")
   contents = file.read()
   contents = contents.split(',')[1:]
   for x in contents:

     device = copy.deepcopy(device) #creates a deep copy of the values of previous dictionary.  
     #device now references a completely new object

     # do some text stripping
     x = x.split(' ')
     device['ip']=x[0]
     device['mac']=x[1]
     listofdevices.append(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the appending of the list. When you append an item(in your case a dictionary). It does not create a dictionary, But it simply places the reference.

It should work if you can initialise the dictionary in the for loop every time, So a new reference is created.

```
listofdevices = []
def begin():
   file = open("outputfromterminal")
   contents = file.read()
   contents = contents.split(',')[1:]
   for x in contents:
     # do some text stripping
     x = x.split(' ')
     device =  { 'ip': '', 'mac': '', 'username': 'admin', 'password': [], 'device type': '', }
     device['ip']=x[0]
     device['mac']=x[1]
     listofdevices.append(device)
```